# Help me recurrence relation , combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, problem-solving

Help me!

For each non-negative integer n let c(n), denote the number of lists of n numbers
each chosen from {0, 1, 2} but with no two consecutive 1s and no two consecutive
2s. So, for example, c(3) = 17, the seventeen lists being

000, 001, 002, 010, 012, 020, 021, 100,
101, 102, 120, 121, 200, 201, 202, 210, 212.

Show that the c(n)s satisfy the recurrence relation
c(0) = 1, c(1) = 3 and c(n) = 2c(n-1 )+ c(n-2) (n > 1).

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What have you tried? You're already given the recurrence relation, and the somewhat obvious conditioning seems to work, so ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $d(n), e(n), f(n)$ refer to the number of such strings that end with 0, 1, 2.

Clearly, we have
$c(n) = d(n) + e(n) + f(n) $
$ e(n) = f(n)$
$d(n) = d(n-1) + e(n-1) + f(n-1)$
$e(n) = d(n-1) + f(n-1)$
$f(n) = d(n-1) + e(n-1)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry I can't, I do not understand this part

Comment: What have you tried? Based on what I've written, what would your next step be? Where are you stuck at? If you can give answers to those questions, I can help you figure out the next steps.